# shrepoint 2007 workflow retrieve group of values

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have two lists that i would like to use to create a workflow that sends email whenever an item is created.

Here the details:

List *Officers* has two columns, **City** and **Officer** and there clearly are lots of officers per city. in the second list *Enquiry* there is one field *City* (mandatory), so basically i want that when a new item is created in *Enquiry* the workflow lookup the city in the *Officers* list and send an email to all the officers in that city.

Any idea on how i could achieve this?
i don't have access to the sharepoint server and i don't know how to work with visual studio, c# etc. just plain SPD 2007

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I would have my list of Officers have one city listed and the Officer column be set to either a person/group field with multiple selections possible or a plain text multiline field where I would put in email addresses delimited by semicolons. Then in my workflow, I'd look up that particular field store it in a variable and use it in my email.

SPD doesn't give you options to store collections of data like that.